# vba - Too many shapes slow down the code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with about 600 shapes.

One of them (just one) is assigned to a macro that opens a simple userform.

When i click on it, it takes too much time to open the userform.

When I delete all other shapes, it opens faster.

I would really appreciate your help to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the code that is under the UserForm_Activate()? Is there something running on open of the form?

Comment: There is no code under the UserForm_Activate event.

Comment: Tried restart excell? I have 600shapes too and nothing affects the userforms, and i have many complex userforms, still very fast.

Comment: Yes I tried to restart excel .. even restarted windows but nothing changed. I don't know what's the relation between the no. of shapes and opening a userform with no initialize code??!!! The strange thing is that when i delete all the shapes the userform opens in about 0.1 second :(

Answer (score 0):

Everytime that you code runs just hide the shapes. It helps.

```
Function ShapeNichtSehen(True_or_False As MsoTriState)
Dim Sh As Shape
   For Each Sh In Shapes
      Sh.Visible = True_or_False
   Next Sh
End Function
```